# wordpress multi user - user session is lost on ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a  WordPress multi user site where registered users can save some meta information in front end of the main site(a user dashboard interface). To save this info i'm using ajax calls that looks like this

```
jQuery.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: ajaxurl,
         data: {
            'action'           :   'function_name',
            'pay_tip'          :    pay_tip,
        },
        success: function (data) {  
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (errorThrown) {
        console.log(errorThrown);
      }
    });//end ajax
```

the php action

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_function_name', 'function_name' );  
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_function_name', 'function_name' ); // this will be removed since the action is only for logged in users 


function function_name(){
    $current_user                   =   wp_get_current_user();
    $userID                         =   $current_user->ID;
    $user_login                     =   $current_user->user_login;

    print_r($current_user);

    if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {   
        exit('no session');
    }
    ...
```

The problem is that in the php function the user session is lost and wordpress is not considering the user as logged in.

In the user dashboard (the page where is the save button) the wp_get_current_user() returns the correct info but somehow this data is lost when ajax calls are made.

The ajaxurl variable in js is https://www.website.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
Also the   print get_current_blog_id(); on the user dashboard and the ajax php function returns 1 - the id of the main blog.

Thank you

Comment: Define different functions for logged in users and not logged in users

Comment: there are no different functions - there is only 1 ajax function that is called via the add_action  add_action( 'wp_ajax_function_name', 'function_name' );

Comment: I think the AJAX header conflict with current session and get session ended. Just refer the ajax response header its helps you find answer

Comment: The problem was a "https setup" one - the calls were made from https url while the answers come with http. Thanks for the tip GNANA